# Which Prometheus metrics type to use for reporting purchase amount

Tags: prometheus

Which prometheus metrics type to use for reporting cart order / purchase amount? Should I use gauge or histogram?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why not using counter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The needed metric type depends on the type of reports you need from the `purchasing amount` metric.

For example, if you want to know the total amount of purchases over arbitrary period of time, then you need to use a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter), which must be incremented whenever new purchase is made. The counter may contain additional labels if finer-grained reports are needed. For example, it may contain `shop` label if you want receiving purchasing stats individually per each shop. Or it may contain `product_id` label if you need per-product purchasing stats. Note that too fine-grained label can lead to [high cardinality issues](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-cardinality).

If you want to know the distribution of purchasing amounts across purchases, then you need to use [histogram](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram).

Note that you can use both histograms and counters if you need both report types.